# Открытие страницы на якорь

Tags: html

Есть две страницы, на одной ссылки(1), на другой список(2). Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на определенную ссылку страницы (1) открывалась страница (2) в нужном месте?

Comment: http://tehnopost.info/html/10-yakor-ankor-na-veb-stranice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице 1:

```
<a href="page2.html#ancor1">Ссылка на якорь 1</a>
<a href="page2.html#ancor2">Ссылка на якорь 2</a>
<a href="page2.html#ancor3">Ссылка на якорь 3</a>
<a href="page2.html#ancor4">Ссылка на якорь 4</a>
```

На странице 2:

```
<a name="ancor1"></a><h2>Блок 1</h2>
<a name="ancor2"></a><h2>Блок 2</h2>
<a name="ancor3"></a><h2>Блок 3</h2>
<a name="ancor4"></a><h2>Блок 4</h2>
```

Comment: Более универсальным решением будет использование id вместо name.